# Wordpress page has an index template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I created some pages templates in wordpress and these don't work.

I create pages in `wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page` with the new template(I selected the template at 'Template') and when I access every page the template is like `index.php/home` template.. The custom template is not showing...

Can someone help me?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Make sure you have followed this: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/ if you are still stuck please paste the full code, file name and location of your template file

Comment: I followed these steps. I made the page like there but doesn't works.